# Firebase native is conflicting with Firebase JS in Ionic3 app ( Push notifications Enabling issue)

Tags: firebase, ionic3, angularfire2

I want to use firebase chatting with push notifications. I purchased a code sample for this and no plugin conflict is there in that piece of code. I am having a plugin conflict of Firebase native with a red line below. I am attaching a screenshot of the code

I tried removing the node_modules folder. Remove platform Android. Adding it again. running command npm I for installing node_modules folder again. The problem remains the same

Push notifications should work. Right now messaging is working perfect but when I try to enable push notifications the plugin conflict comes in

```
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { UserProvider } from '../../providers/user/user';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { config } from '../../app/app.angularfireconfig'
@Injectable()
export class FcmProvider {
userId;
fireuserStatus = firebase.database().ref('/userstatus');

constructor(
public userservice: UserProvider,
private http: Http,
public afs: AngularFirestore,
public firebaseNative: Firebase
) {
}
```

Comment: Please post the code (not as screenshot) and the exact error messages.

Comment: Please update the question with formatted code instead of the comment. Everything required to answered should be up there.

Comment: Just add only one import, use "import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';" or "import firebase from 'firebase'",  do not use both.

Comment: "import firebase from 'firebase' is necessary because its used to access the database. In the code. Also I have bought a code which is working fine with both of these. The only problem I see is kind of some conflict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it myself. I am answering it lets hope it helps someone. Just downgrade the Firebase plugin to version 4.20.0. It won't ask you for adding /ngx at the end and you can use firebase by staying in ionic3

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
npm install @ionic-native/firebase@4.20.0

Run these commands and your problem will be solved.